# Simplifying expression involving Boson operators

Tags: simplifying-expressions, evaluation, physics

I want to do calculations involving Boson operators $a(k), a^{\dagger}(k)$, e.g $(x + a(k))(y+a^{\dagger}(k))$. My code is:

```
NCM[x___] := NonCommutativeMultiply[x];
NCM[] := 1
NCM[___, 0, ___] := 0
NCM[H___, 1, T___] := NCM[H, T]

NCM[left___, a[k1_], SuperDagger[a][k2_], right___] := 
NCM[left, SuperDagger[a][k2], a[k1], right] + 
NCM[left, right]*KroneckerDelta[k1 - k2]

Unprotect[NCM];
NCM[left___, HoldPattern[Times[id, x_]], right___] := 
x  NCM[left, right]
NCM[left___, HoldPattern[Times[a[k_], x_]], right___] := 
x   NCM[left, a[k], right]
NCM[left___, HoldPattern[Times[SuperDagger[a][k_], x_]], right___] := 
x NCM[left, SuperDagger[a][k], right]

Protect[NCM];
```

where based on [Simplifying expression with non-commutating entries](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/87101/simplifying-expression-with-non-commutating-entries)
I introduced the unit `id` and based on [Boson Commutation relations](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/95616/boson-commutation-relations)'s first reply I constructed the $[a(k),a^{\dagger}(k')]=\delta_{kk'}$ relation.

Now if I try:

```
Distribute[(x id + a[k]) ** (y id - SuperDagger[a][k])]
(* I get *)
(id x) ** (id y) + (id x) ** (-SuperDagger[a][k]) + a[k] ** (id y) + 
a[k] ** (-SuperDagger[a][k])
```

and not `x y -x SuperDagger[a][k] + y a[k] - a[k] **SuperDagger[a][k]`

I can't figure out why...

Comment: It looks like it did everything you told it to do, exactly as you told it to do it. Why do you expect that `id` & the selective instances of `NCM`, `**`, will just disappear?

Comment: in [Simplifying expression with non-commutating entries](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/87101/simplifying-expression-with-non-commutating-entries) the output of `Distribute[(a id + X) ** (b id - Y)]` is `a b id + b X - a Y - X ** Y ` I can't achieve that